# selenium: Uploading a large file using send_keys using python

Tags: selenium, centos, python-2.6

I am trying to use Selenium to upload a 960KB file on the machine that's running the browser interaction using **send_keys**, the file is being sent to a different machine. Currently this is not working and I get the following traceback below. However it works when an image or small zipped file is being uploaded (so I don't think it's a problem with uploading a zipped file which is what others have had issues with). I tried to search topics before posting:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/selenium-users/dlxoowrZYeA/24kPjqRW2FcJ[1-25]
http://grokbase.com/t/gg/selenium-developer-activity/124tpkyzmq/issue-3812-in-selenium-python-cannot-upload-a-file

However after making the suggested edits, it still is not working. **I am using selenium 2.25.0, a centos 6.3 operating system and Python 2.6.6**

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/testrunner/Suite/CATS/cobalt/cobalttest.py", line 270, in run
  testMethod()
  File "/home/testrunner/Suite/CATS/mhetest/psmBaseSetupModule.py", line 549, in runTest
    PSM.command().find_element_by_name( 'location' ).send_keys(  'filename.tar.gz' )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 144, in send_keys
value = self._upload(local_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 228, in _upload
{'file': base64.encodestring(fp.getvalue())})['value']
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 205, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 154, in execute
response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 283, in execute
return self._request(url, method=command_info[0], data=data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 324, in _request
response = opener.open(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 391, in open
response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 409, in _open
'_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1190, in http_open
return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1163, in do_open
r = h.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 990, in getresponse
response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 391, in begin
version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 355, in _read_status
**raise BadStatusLine(line)
BadStatusLine**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved when downgrading Firefox to Firefox 5. I am unsure how to upload the file with a more recent version of Firefox.